# Populate dictionaries from text file

Tags: python, file, io, dictionary

I have a text file with the details of a set of restaurants given one after the other. The details are name, rating, price and type of cuisines of a particular restaurant. The contents of text file is as given below.

```
George Porgie
87%
$$$
Canadian, Pub Food

Queen St. Cafe
82%
$
Malaysian, Thai

Dumpling R Us
71%
$
Chinese

Mexican Grill
85%
$$
Mexican

Deep Fried Everything
52%
$
Pub Food
```

I want to create a set of dictionaries as given below:

```
Restaurant name to rating:
# dict of {str : int}
name_to_rating = {'George Porgie' : 87,
'Queen St. Cafe' : 82,
'Dumpling R Us' : 71,
'Mexican Grill' : 85,
'Deep Fried Everything' : 52}

Price to list of restaurant names:
# dict of {str : list of str }
price_to_names = {'$'   :  ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumpling R Us', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
'$$'  :  ['Mexican Grill'],
'$$$' :  ['George Porgie'], 
'$$$$' : [ ]}

Cuisine to list of restaurant name:
#dic of {str : list of str }
cuisine_to_names = {'Canadian' : ['George Porgie'],
'Pub Food' : ['George Porgie', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
'Malaysian' : ['Queen St. Cafe'],
'Thai' : ['Queen St. Cafe'],
'Chinese' : ['Dumpling R Us'],
'Mexican' : ['Mexican Grill']}
```

What is the best way in Python to populate the above dictionaries ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I know only to read lines one by one from text file using Python

Comment: This is a homework from Coursera.

Comment: @ Bibhas. This example is from coursera indeed. But this is not a homework which carries any credit in the course. If it was an exercise which carries credit, I would not have asked it here. Kindly do not comment if you cannot provide anything constructive.

Comment: This is something that, pretty significantly turns up in the earlier course - which you can still audit. Its going to help *massively* if you get access to that course, and read these things up. I realise the textbook dosen't have this either, but its probably better to help yourself in this case. Take a look at learning to program week 6 and 7

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : That is what i mean constructive. Thanks!. Bibhas : Now you know what is constructive.

Comment: Well, doing that might have rendered this question redundant. I'd note that the course staff *are* aware of people asking questions on sites such as this. I believe that bibas pointing this out is really both for your own good (you don't want to get kicked out of the course) and the benefit of those who're trying out the assignments yourself. There's a certain learning experience to be gained from metaphorically beating the answer into shape.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes you are right!. I did wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: @LinuxPenseur Thanks for educating me. Now I know that I *should* point out when people are posting their homework. :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialise some containers:

```
name_to_rating = {}
price_to_names = collections.defaultdict(list)
cuisine_to_names = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Read your file into a temporary string:

```
with open('/path/to/your/file.txt') as f:
  spam = f.read().strip()
```

Assuming the structure is consistent (i.e. chunks of 4 lines separated by double newlines), iterate through the chunks and populate your containers:

```
restraunts = [chunk.split('\n') for chunk in spam.split('\n\n')]
for name, rating, price, cuisines in restraunts:
  name_to_rating[name] = rating
  # etc ..
```

Answer (score 0):

for the main reading loop, you can use enumerate and modulo to know what is the data on a line:

```
for lineNb, line in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
    print lineNb, lineNb%4, line
```

for the `price_to_names` and `cuisine_to_names` dictionnaries, you could use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
price_to_names = defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: @ niroyb: I am working on your answer. Thank you so much. Will get back.